# How could I change the height of title bar on QDockWidget?

Tags: qt, titlebar, qdockwidget

I use the following code:

```
int SWStyle::pixelMetric( PixelMetric which, const QStyleOption *option, const QWidget *widget ) const
{
    switch (which)
    {
    case PM_DefaultFrameWidth:
        return 1;
    case PM_TitleBarHeight:
        return 80;
    default:
        return QCleanlooksStyle::pixelMetric(which, option, widget);
    }
}

--------------------------------------------
myQdockWidget->setStyle(new SWStyle);
```

to change the height of title bar, but it doesn't work, it can change frame width.

could title bar height of QDockWidget be changed?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the `Qt` source (version 5.8) it doesn't appear to use `PM_TitleBarHeight` when calculating the title height.  Instead it uses a combination of `QFontMetrics::height()` and the pixel metric for `QStyle::PM_DockWidgetTitleMargin` (from the `Qt` source)...

```
QFontMetrics titleFontMetrics = q->fontMetrics();
int mw = q->style()->pixelMetric(QStyle::PM_DockWidgetTitleMargin, 0, q);

return qMax(buttonHeight + 2, titleFontMetrics.height() + 2*mw);
```

So updating your `SWStyle::pixelMetric` override to provide a case for `QStyle::PM_DockWidgetTitleMargin` might be a good starting point.

Apart from that you can always pass your own custom title widget to [`QDockWidget::setTitleBarWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdockwidget.html#setTitleBarWidget).